# Retrieve an embedded document using Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a Mongoid document called Equipment which can embed multiple Question documents. Here are the document schemas:

```
class Equipment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :description
  field :modelNumber
  field :title
  field :categoryId
  field :subCategoryId
  field :stateId
  field :city
  field :askingPrice

  embeds_many :questions

end

class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :content

  attr_accessible :content

  embedded_in :equipment, :inverse_of => :questions
  embeds_one :answers
end
```

My issue is that I can retrieve a Question document based on the Question Id. However, my current query returns the parent Equipment document. I would have expected the query to return the embedded Question document. I can eventually get the embedded Question document but I have to loop through all the Question documents of the parent Equipment document.

Here is my current query:

```
@question = Equipment.where('questions._id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(params[:id])).first
```

Is there a way to directly obtain the embedded Question document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using embedded documents, grabbing a single question may not make sense. It does, however, make sense in the context of the parent document. If you really just want a specific question, you can just use normal ARish syntax:

```
question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

I would strongly suggest you make sure you have an index on the `question._id` field. This will help ensure this query is a fast read operation. Otherwise, Mongo will need to run through all of the `Equipment` documents and check each of the embedded `Question` objects.

If the above doesn't work, you can try a nested relation:

```
Equipment.find(params[:equipment_id]).questions.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The two suggestions you offered did not work for me. :-( However, this does work for me: equipment = Equipment.find(params[:id])
    question = equipment.questions.find(params[:question_id]) . Any thoughts on how I can combine these two queries into one?

Comment: @RichBlumer that's basically the 2nd query I wrote. You just have different names for your params. `question = Equipment.find(params[:id]).questions.find(params[:question_id])`

Comment: I agree. My issue was I couldn't chain them together like you did. Always got an error on questions, no such method. I just tried it like  you have it chaining them together and IT works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is my understanding/experience that your first query `question = Question.find(params[:id])` will never work on an embedded document. Does creating an index on the parent change this?

Comment: @emkman I believe it works when you use the IdentityMap and have already retrieved that question once via the nested method.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks @AaronK. I just wrote this really ugly code: `shared_profile = User.find_by('profiles.share_token' => params[:share_token] ).profiles.find_by(share_token: params[:share_token])` and I wish there was a way to clean it up.

Comment: @emkman That may mean it's time to not use embedded documents and just move to a normal `has_many`.

Comment: @AaronK Agreed, I just need to see if this is the common case or the exception. There may be some refactoring in my future :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With rails (3.2.15) and mongoid (3.1.5)  I can only do it in this way:

```
@equipment = Equipment.where('questions._id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(params[:id])).first
@question = @equipment.questions.find(params[:id])
```